# Генерация дерева Nested Sets

Tags: javascript

Реализовать функцию `drawNestedSetsTree(data, node)`, которая принимает на вход два аргумента:

- `data` - массив из `0` или более узлов, каждый элемент которого содержит поля

  - `title` (имя узла),
  - `left` (левая граница) и
  - `right` (правая граница).

  Формат хранения - Nested Sets
- `node` - DOM-узел (можете считать что это будет `div`), в который надо вывести итоговую структуру в виде дерева `ul` и `li`

Функция `drawNestedSetsTree()` выводит в переданный DOM-узел визуализацию дерева, которое лежит в data.

Входной массив data и результат работы функции имеют вид:

```js
[
  {
    title: "Одежда",
    left: 1,
    right: 22
  },
  {
    title: "Мужская",
    left: 2,
    right: 9
  },
  {
    title: "Женская",
    left: 10,
    right: 21
  },
  {
    title: "Костюмы",
    left: 3,
    right: 8
  },
  {
    title: "Платья",
    left: 11,
    right: 16
  },
  {
    title: "Юбки",
    left: 17,
    right: 18
  },
  {
    title: "Блузы",
    left: 19,
    right: 20
  },
  {
    title: "Брюки",
    left: 4,
    right: 5
  },
  {
    title: "Жакеты",
    left: 6,
    right: 7
  },
  {
    title: "Вечерние",
    left: 12,
    right: 13
  },
  {
    title: "Летние",
    left: 14,
    right: 15
  }
];
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Одежда
    <ul>
      <li>Мужская
        <ul>
          <li>Костюмы
            <ul>
              <li>Брюки</li>
              <li>Жакеты</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Женская
        <ul>
          <li>Платья
            <ul>
              <li>Вечерние</li>
              <li>Летние</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Юбки</li>
          <li>Блузы</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Интересует алгоритм решения таких задач.

Comment: я не понял что означают `left` и `right` и как они влияют на положение в дереве

Comment: а, все, нарисовать надо было.

Comment: _Интересует алгоритм решения таких задач._ - таких, это каких?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nested Sets** - формат хранения дерева каталогов, в каждом из которых прописана пара колонок left и right, хранящие диапазон всех вложенных элементов, например, корень дерева из 9 элементов будет иметь левое значение ''1'', а правое — ''18''.

[Ссылка на wiki.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

Вот пример, как можно отрисовать вложенный HTML список на JS с использованием данных NS исходя из твоей задачи:

```
/**
  * Функция принимает 2 значения:
  * @param data - массив Nested Sets
  * @param node - DOM элемент
  */
function drawNestedSetsTree(data, node) {
  node.innerHTML = ''; // Очищаем от дочерних элементов

  if (data.length) { // Проверяем есть ли данные
    var ul = document.createElement('ul'); // Создаём контейнер <ul>
    var tree = fetchChildElement(ul); // Создаём дерево
    node.appendChild(tree); // Добавляем дерево в наш node элемент
  }

  /**
    * Функция создаёт и возвращает готовое HTML дерево:
    * @param container - DOM элемент, контейнер для дерева
    * @param left - минимальное значение left (не обязательный)
    * @param right - максимальноее значение right (не обязательный)
    */
  function fetchChildElement(container, left, right) {
    data.filter(filterItems); // Перебираем массив данных
    return container;

    function filterItems(item) {
      if (item.left === (left || 1)) {
        var element = document.createElement('li');
        element.innerHTML = item.title;

        // Здесь мы проверяем есть ли у данного элемента
        // вложенные элементы. Если такие имеються, то для
        // них вызываем функцию заново.
        if (item.left + 1 < item.right) {
          var childContainer = document.createElement('ul');
          var child = fetchChildElement(childContainer, item.left + 1, item.right - 1);
          element.appendChild(child);
        }

        // Добавляем в контейнер новый элемент
        container.appendChild(element);

        // Здесь мы проверяем есть ли последующие элементы
        // и вызываем для них функцию.
        if (right && item.right < right) {
          fetchChildElement(container, item.right + 1, right);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Рабочий пример здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/zzzoryn/z7pfhk08/)

Answer (score -1):

тоже пытаешься сделать тестовое задание?))
Нашел более подходящее для нас решение :

```
function drawNestedSetsTree(data, node) {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  data = data.sort((first, second) => {
    if (first.left > second.left) return 1;
    if (first.left < second.left) return -1;
  });

  let counts = data.length;
  console.log('counts',counts);
  for (let i = 0; i < counts; i++ ) {
    let item = data[i];
    console.log('item', item.title);
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = item.title;
    if ((item.right - item.left) == 1) {
      ul.appendChild(li);
    } else {
      data.splice(0, 1);
      let children = data.filter(x => x.left < item.right);
      data.splice(0, children.length);
      counts = counts - (children.length + 1);
      console.log('i', i);
      if (children.length > 0) {
        child = drawNestedSetsTree(children, li);
      }
      ul.appendChild(child);
    }
  };
  node.appendChild(ul);
  return node;
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = drawNestedSetsTree;
}
```

- вот еще хороший материал, для более глубокого изучения http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html

удачи)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/190657)

Comment: ок, на будущее учту замечание.Сам сижу и разбираюсь в этом вопросе-пипец как это сложно. Буксую на ровном месте.

Comment: исправил, оформил как положено

Comment: опиши словами, что делает твой код

Comment: @ЮрийГапончук +1 к Grundy: без пояснений и комментариев в этом коде будет сложно разобраться. (Не потому, что код какой-то особенный, в любом коде сложно разбираться без пояснений).